# python: argparser.add_argument() causes ArgumentError()

Tags: python, arguments, parameter-passing

I've encountered a very strange issue — when I'm using `argparser.add_argument()` method I'm getting `ArgumentError()`.

```
from oauth2client.tools import argparser, run_flow

if __name__ == "__main__":
  argparser.add_argument("--videoid", default="L-oNKK1CrnU",
    help="ID of video to like.")
```

I'm running the code with pdb, that's the error I'm getting:

```
(Pdb) n
ArgumentError: ArgumentError()
> c:\py\googleapitest.py(48)<module>()->None
-> help="ID of video to like.")
```

That's the root cause:

```
C:\Python27\lib\argparse.pyc in _handle_conflict_error(self, action, conflicting_actions)
   1452                                      for option_string, action
   1453                                      in conflicting_actions])
-> 1454         raise ArgumentError(action, message % conflict_string)
```

I'm getting the error even if I'm not passing "help" param.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is `argparser`?

Comment: @dm295 from oauth2client.tools import argparser

Comment: It would help to see how `argparser` is defined. It would appear there is already an option named `--videoid`.

Comment: `argparser` is actually an `argparse` parser: https://github.com/google/oauth2client/blob/master/oauth2client/tools.py#L51. There's no `--videoid` option in the code. Moreover, I tried out the example code and it works for me (i.e. doesn't raise an error). But I use GNU/Linux, and I see that OP runs the code on Windows — could argparse behave differently there?

Comment: `pdb` shows that you are on line 48 (`c:\py\googleapitest.py(48)`) so you aren't showing us the script that has the problem. The error suggests that you are adding the same option twice, so those other lines are relevant.

Comment: @golosovsky, what is the actual error message and traceback? Judging from your root cause listing, there should be a message.

Comment: You are trying to add "--videoid" twice. It could be in this module or another module that you import that also uses `oauth2client.tools.argparser` to set the argument.

Comment: @tdelaney wekritter The thing is that there's really no --video argument in tools.py's argparser. Each time I'm trying to use it (just address it ("argparser") or like that -- http://chopapp.com/#e09u1te3) -- I'm getting this error: "ArgumentError: argument --videoid: conflicting option string(s): --videoid".  When I implement the "argparser" myself, and add all the arguments from _CreateArgumentParser() method at tools.py's soruce (https://github.com/google/oauth2client/blob/master/oauth2client/tools.py) -- everything works fine

Comment: Now I'm inclined to think that --videoid does get added to argparser somewhere else in your code, like @tdelaney says. Can you check it out? As a simple test for that hypothesis, please try to run the exact code from your first listing and see if the error is raised.

Comment: Also, I grepped through `oauth2client` code and there is no `videoid`occurence whatsoever.

Comment: Just before you add your argument, see what's already in there with `argparser.print_help()`. if you see the argument before you add it, somebody else did it.

Comment: Try running just the example you showed us. There error should be on line 5, not line 48. You are doing other stuff and that's where the error is, not in the oauth2client module. Serach your code for the string.

Comment: @werkritter tdelaney as you asked -- I've just performed a test and you were absolutely right. I was running all my tests from same IPYTHON window. I was sure that execution %reset after each run resets the entire environment. I just found out it's not. But I wonder how google really suggest to implement it this way if it's a "one time show"? I can the code only once and then it fails; while running a version of the code with a "local" argparser each time will work every time. Do you have any thoughts on that? Thank you very much for helping!

Comment: @werkritter tdelaney maybe the whole issue solution is to just to wrap the code Google haveve suggested in a method and then include the "import" statements inside the method? Maybe this way oauth2client.tools.argparser will be "local"? Thanks.

Comment: If you create your own parser like the docs and my deleted answer suggests (I may have to undelete it), then it will work because you'll recreate your own parser instead of updating the existing parser.

Comment: @tdelaney yes, sure -- I understand that. I'm trying to understand why Google suggest to use the argparser?

Comment: The docs I reference show the right way... maybe there are conflicting examples, but the reference is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [auth2 docs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth):

> The oauth2client.tools.run_flow() function is controlled by
>   command-line flags, and the Python standard library argparse module
>   must be initialized at the start of your program. Argparse is included
>   in Python 2.7+, and is available as a separate package for older
>   versions. The following shows an example of how to use this function:

```
import argparse
from oauth2client import tools

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser])
flags = parser.parse_args()
```

**Back From The Dead**

The original problem arises after restarting the script in some environment such as `pdb`. On restart, the main script runs again but old imported scripts, including changes to `oath2client.tools.argparser` remain. The solution is as stated in the docs, create your own parser with oauth2client's parser as a parent. That way, you only add your arguments to a parser that is recreated on startup.

Comment: While OP doesn't follow the practice outlined in the docs, your answer doesn't really address his problem — the error is raised when `argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument` is called on `argparser`, which should be possible in principle.

Comment: @werkritter I've followed the instructions on Google's guide — https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python#rate__like__a_video

Comment: @werkritter I took a closer look at the source and you are right. This isn't going to solve the problem! I'll delete it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initilize a parser. I'd just do this (I think oauth.tools is really linking to argparse anyway):

```
import argparse

def main(args):
    pass
    #reference args.videoid to use in the code

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--videoid", dest='videoid',default="L-oNKK1CrnU", help="ID of video to like.")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args)
```

Comment: As the OP's third code listing shows, argparser does use argparse from stdlib. Another proof: https://github.com/google/oauth2client/blob/master/oauth2client/tools.py#L51. So there is no need to initialize a parser when using oauth2client.tools.argparser.

Comment: This isn't quite right. You need to add the oath argparser as the parent to get its options added to your command line.

Comment: Well, while that may not be a good practice, I don't see why in principle you couldn't use `argparser` directly. It would be problematic only if you'd need to create more than parser, each of which would then need to have `argparser` as a parent.

Comment: @werkritter in any case I'm using argparser (like here - http://chopapp.com/#e09u1te3) I'm getting errors. When I implement myself the argparser using argparse, including the exact arguments from the tools.py module (https://github.com/google/oauth2client/blob/master/oauth2client/tools.py) -- everything works fine. It doesn't work only if I'm tying to use their argparser. That's very strange. Maybe it's really an OS issue

Comment: btw that's the error when I'm using tools.py's argparser ArgumentError: argument --videoid: conflicting option string(s): --videoid